# Will pre-padding Tcl dicts with empty values speed up runtime?

Tags: tcl

While solving one of the Advent of Code 2021 puzzles in Tcl, I wanted to speed up the runtime of my script.

My script uses a dictionary with keys as {x y} coordinates and a 0 or 1 as the value.  The x-y area of interest for the puzzle increases for each iteration of a loop.  As a result, additional key-value pairs are added to the dict with each iteration of the loop.

I think I once learned that Tcl dicts may become re-structured in memory if necessary, possibly due to adding more and more keys.  If so, does this cause a runtime hit?

To speed up runtime, would it be a good idea to pre-pad a dict with keys set to empty strings matching the expected final size of the dict?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the implementation level, yes, rebuilding the hash table has a cost that is linear in the number of entries; after all, each entry has to be placed in a new bucket of the enlarged hash table array. However, the entries themselves do not need to be reallocated; the only memory management changes are for the hash table arrays themselves (allocate new, dispose old) so the cost isn't crazy high. The rebuild triggers whenever the number of entries in the hash table exceeds a fixed multiplier of the size of the hash table; that loading factor is a compile time constant. (Dicts are wrappers around hash tables with `Tcl_Obj` keys, mostly to add value semantics and ensure that the iteration order is consistent; those aren't things that matter for the rebuild semantics.) There's no notion of pre-sizing a hash table; the implementation doesn't expose that in a useful way. It also doesn't shrink the array; once it has grown, it stays grown (and most of the time that's not a problem at all).

The complexities of rebuild semantics are part of why Tcl's associative arrays are said to have a random order of enumeration: it's not actually random, but the deterministic algorithm is sensitive to a lot of factors that people normally ignore. You don't need to care about that when working with dicts, where the order of iteration is exactly knowable from the way that the value was built, irrespective of the details of how the hashing is done.

---

If you're doing lookups using compact integer keys from 0 up, a list will be substantially faster, as hashing is currently always performed on string representations. Compound integer keys may become nested lists.

Comment: Summary: there's a rebuild cost, but you almost always don't need to care about it, even in performance-sensitive applications.

Comment: Thank you very much.  I'll try re-implementing with a nested list to eliminate the hashing entirely.    I'll need to offset my {0 0} origin to somewhere in the middle of a nested list (with padding both directions) to allow negative coordinates.